# Feeding Torch objects from csv to learn

Tags: python, csv, pytorch, torch

I am trying to give PyTorch the input to build a very simple Neural Network. Here is my problem:
I have all the data I want to use in an csv and I am using Panda to read it.
Here is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("../myFile.csv")
input = [x for x in data]
input = np.asarray(input)
input = torch.from_numpy(input)
```

This returns the error:

```
line 42, in <module>
input = torch.from_numpy(input)
TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.str_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, int64, int32, int16, int8, and uint8.
```

I understand what the error means. The main problem is, that there are a few columns in my csv that can not be casted to int or float as they are basically Strings, for example the customer-ID would be something like: AAABBBCCC; and i can not cast that to float or int. Do you have any idea what I can do?

EDIT: Here is my new updated code with the proposed answer by Anubhav:

```
data = pd.read_csv("myFile.csv", names=col_names)
data = data.drop(["Customer-ID", "name"], axis=1)

for column in list(data):
    # one hot encode of Object Columns
    one_hot = pd.get_dummies(data[column])
    # drop encoded columns
    data = data.drop(column, axis=1)
    # join the encoded data
    data = data.join(one_hot)

print(data.dtypes)

inp = [x for x in data]
inp = np.asarray(inp, dtype=np.float32)
inp = torch.from_numpy(inp)
```

But I still get the following error:

```
line 52, in <module>
    inp = np.asarray(inp, dtype=np.float32)
  File "C:\Users\Paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '01139_Lichtenau'
```

Looking up this value from print(data.dtypes) it clearly says:

```
01139_Lichtenau  uint8
```

Did the encoding fail for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty explicit here, you have some string in your array that can't be converted to tensor. You can convert all the numerical variable into tensors, but you have to do something about the strings. You can drop all the columns containing strings (not optimal), one hot encode your categories, or what I would suggest is to embed your category before feeding this to your feed forward Neural Network.

Fastai (a library built on top on pytorch) has a `Tabular` section that might be able to help you buit your network more easily, you might want to check that out :https://docs.fast.ai/tabular.html (It will perform the embedding of the categorical variable and some preprocessing for you).

Comment: It looks promising, but I still struggle to bring the pieces together. Does someone have some example code I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the output of `[x for x in data]` ? It's just the list of column names, which are of type string. That's why, you are getting above error. Now, I will help you solve your problem using a sample `csv` file.

Filename: `data.csv`

```
custID name age salary label
EMP1 Mahi 23 120000 Yes
EMP2 Tom 28 200000 No
EMP3 Chris 25 123000 No
EMP4 Matt 29 2130000 Yes
EMP5 Brown 27 324675 Yes
```

As you can see, above file contains both string and integer values. First, I will show the output of your code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=' ')
inp = [x for x in data]   # ['custID', 'name', 'age', 'salary', 'label']
inp = np.asarray(inp)     # array(['custID', 'name', 'age', 'salary', 'label'], dtype='<U6')
inp = torch.from_numpy(inp)
```

> TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.str_. The only
>   supported types are: double, float, float16, int64, int32, and uint8

What you can do is consider only those string column are important for the neural networks and that you can `one-hot` encode. Columns like `custID` and `name` don't have any significance as far as neural network is concerned.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=' ')

# one-hot encode of column 'label'
# Get one hot encoding of column 'label'
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(data['label'])
# Drop column 'label' as it is now encoded
data = data.drop('label',axis = 1)
# Join the encoded data
data = data.join(one_hot)

inp = [data[x] for x in data]
inp = np.asarray(inp[2:], dtype=np.float32)
inp = torch.from_numpy(inp)
```

output:

```
tensor([[     23.,      28.,      25.,      29.,      27.],
        [ 120000.,  200000.,  123000., 2130000.,  324675.],
        [      0.,       1.,       1.,       0.,       0.],
        [      1.,       0.,       0.,       1.,       1.]])
```

In the above code, I have first one-hot encoded the column `label`, then I dropped that column and joined the encoded data. After that, I read all the columns of the `csv` file(including `custID` and `name`), then ignoring `custID` and `name` columns and converting others to float and finally using `torch.from_numpy` to convert it to tensor.

In the above output, every row corresponds to a column in `one-hot` encoded data.

Comment: Please look up my edit, I don't have enough space in the comment section, thank you for your efforts so far!

Comment: @NoChance, in this loop `for column in list(data):`, you are doing one-hot encoding of all columns which also includes columns which are already integer or float. Is this what you want ?

Comment: Not really, that was just for testing purposes to get things going in the first place to see if it works. Is that causing a problem?

Comment: can you provide some sample data what you are using right now?